# Eclipse SWT: How to disable scrolledcomposite scrolling on mousewheel

Tags: java, eclipse, canvas, swt, listeners

so I have

A Part with : (I will spare you the layout details, it's just to show my setup)

```
sc = new ScrolledComposite(parent, SWT.V_SCROLL | SWT.H_SCROLL);
    sc.setExpandHorizontal(true);
    sc.setExpandVertical(true);
    drawingPane = new Composite(sc, SWT.NONE);
    drawingPane.setBackground(parent.getDisplay().getSystemColor(SWT.COLOR_BLACK));
    sc.setContent(drawingPane);

    paintCanvas = new Canvas(drawingPane, SWT.NO_REDRAW_RESIZE | SWT.NO_BACKGROUND);
```

When I add then a `MouseWheelListener` to the Canvas, each Time the event occurs, the vertical Scrollbar of the ScrolledComposite is also reacting to it.

Which is kind of annoying. I tried the [Solution of this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18613729/disable-mousewheel-in-a-swt-composite). But the Thing is that the Canvas is the Source of the Event, which is right and I need it to be.

The question is more how can I prohibit the MouseEvent to get passed on to the ScrolledComposite?
I also tried to disable the Scrollbar, but this wasn't practical as I have found no place in the Code to re-enable it afterwards. As it seems that the scrolling gets triggered after anything else(like the redraw of my canvas for example).

Answer (score 1):

A bit more Code would be helpful. Anyway, you could try the following:

```
paintCanvas.addListener(SWT.MouseVerticalWheel, new Listener() {

    @Override
    public void handleEvent(Event event) {

        event.doit = false;
    }
});
```

But I don't think that this will work, since `MouseEvents` aren't `TraverseEvents`. I couldn't test it for myself with your code snippet.